# Microprofile Reactive Messaging with Opentracing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, opentracing, microprofile, distributed-tracing

Im playing around with MP Reactive Messaging and MP Opentracing but I cant figure out how to trace the messages send via Reactive Messaging.

Is it even possible to trace the methods which are annotated with @Income / @Outcome?

Answer (score 0):

you should locate a class that extends `import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.spi.IncomingConnectorFactory;` which is dedicated for `@Incoming` and `import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.spi.OutgoingConnectorFactory;` for `@Outgoing`

depending on the extension you are using. You should have that as it is the connector or the part that send and recieve message to the channels